# Multiple radio buttons with simple_form (Star Rating)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, simple-form, simple-form-for

I'm using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and trying to get a custom wrapper working. No luck so far.

I'm looking to create a simple star rating which has 5 radio buttons for every value. The desired output:

```
<fieldset class="rating-new">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
</fieldset>
```

I'm using `simple_form-bootstrap` and understand that I will need to create a custom wrapper to do this but I chased it a lot and can't seem to figure it out.

Thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Try this snippet on codepen [LINK](https://codepen.io/lsirivong/pen/ekBxI)

Comment: Hey @JyotiPathania, the question is more about getting the desired HTML output with simple_form :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @HarlemSquirrel for reminding me of `collection_radio_buttons`. I wanted to create a custom wrapper for it but I settled with tweaking the labels and style to get where I want to:

Here's how I got it working:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :rating, [[5], [4], [3], [2], [1]], :first, :last, item_wrapper_tag: false, boolean_style: :inline do |b| %>
  <%= b.radio_button + b.label {''} %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection radio buttons from https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collection-radio-buttons

```
form_for @something_rated do |f|
  f.collection_radio_buttons :rating, [[1, '1'] ,[2, '2'],[3, '3'],[4, '4'],[5, '5']], :first, :last
end
```

Comment: Hey @HarlemSquirrel, I'm aware of the `collection_radio_buttons` but it generates a whole different layout from the one I need :/ Do you know how I could tweak the wrapper to get the output I need ?

Comment: I believe you can add `item_label_class: 'full'` to help style the labels